# Why is my Power BI dataset in a Premium workspace fast when querying the data is not?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI dataset in a Premium workspace.  The performance is quite good - capable to displaying results from a table with millions of rows within tolerable speeds.

If I try to execute the same query directly in a database tool, it is much slower.

Why is the Power BI dataset much faster?  If a dataset is in a Premium workspace, does it mean it's cloud based?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an [Import model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-dataset-modes-understand?#import-mode) in Power BI the data is loaded into memory and compressed in an efficient columnar structure which performs amazing for analytical queries. Your source system probably has the data on disk in row oriented storage and isn’t as optimized for fast analytical queries.